# Getting total of 'location'

Tags: php

In my database I have a table entitled `db_pilots`, and I'm trying to find the total of pilots from country i.e a total of pilots from `GB`. It's doing just that, but it's sorting by `location` and not the `total`. How can I achieve this?

```
<?php
$country_info = DB::get_results('SELECT COUNT(pilotid) as total, location FROM'.TABLE_PREFIX.'pilots GROUP BY location DESC');

foreach($country_info as $country)
{

?>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><img src="<?php echo Countries::getCountryImage($country->location); ?>" /></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo Countries::getCountryName($country->location); ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $country->total;?></td>
    </tr>

<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an ORDER BY:

```
...GROUP BY location ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: I was contemplating this, but I wasn't sure whether both GROUP BY and ORDER BY could have been used, but it does work. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space after `FROM`:

```
FROM'.TABLE_PREFIX.'pilots
    ^
```

It should be like this:

```
FROM '.TABLE_PREFIX.'pilots
```

Comment: Sorry, it was like this, it's just a mistake I've made during pasting. I'll fix it asap.